# Relation between "amplitudes program" and S-matrix theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I've been hearing about recent progress in amplitudes, which, as I understand, uses unitarity, locality, and Lorentz invariance to find scattering amplitudes (I often hear buzz words like BCFW recursion). I was wondering what the relationship between this research program and the S-matrix theory of the 1960s? I'm not too familiar with either subject, so any historical context and broad-stroke overviews are appreciated.

Comment: [An Introduction to On-shell Recursion Relations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5759).

Comment: in short, in the 60's they expected too much by consistency conditions for scattering  massive spin-0 particles, the less  constrained of all particles, wanting even to catch non-perturbative physics.  Today, much progress have been made by focusing instead on particles with zero mass but non-zero spin, and focusing on perturbative results almost exclusively. The new strategy has been extremely rewarding and real progress has come.

Comment: Are the techniques used similar? Are modern methods based off the results found in the 60s?